# Mongodb finding latest entry not updating after new insert

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am trying learning async programming by making a discord bot, and for the discord bot I am trying to create a bump reminder function. 
My goal for the bump reminder function is to log the first bump, wait two hours, send the reminder message, then wait for a user to bump, validate the bump and log for the second bump, for every successful bump, the bump time will be logged into a mongodb database.
I will also need to design it so that if the bot restart itself, during anytime, it will send the bump reminder based on the most recent bump time that is logged in the mongodb database.

This is my bump reminder class:
https://gist.github.com/bensonchow123/02f321e182d2ce251ce8d08ceb88456e

A bump time out is 2 hours, and there is a bump check loop that is looped for every 10 seconds

```
 @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def _bump_reminder(self):
        if not self.waiting_bump:
            bump_now = await self._check_bump()
            if bump_now:
                await self._send_reminder_message()
```

And for my question, the line `if now > (last_bump_time + timedelta(hours=2)):`doesn't seems to work, it will return true anyways, resulting in the bot keep sending the bump reminder message again and again.
The function to receive the time of last bump from the most recent sucessful bump insert is this:

```
async def _last_bump_time(self):
        last_bump = bump_db.find_one(sort=[('$natural',ASCENDING)])
        last_bump = last_bump["date"]
        return datetime.strptime(last_bump,"%S:%M:%H:%d:%m:%Y:%z")
```

I think the reason that causes this is because in this last_bump_time function, this line `last_bump = bump_db.find_one(sort=[('$natural',ASCENDING)])` which is used to find the most recent database insert, don't seem to update after a successful bump.
 resulting in the bot keep sending the reminder message as now is still > last bump time.
This is the function to find the current time

```
async def _now(self):
        return datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

The function that logs the successful bump into my database is this:

```
async def _log_successful_bump(self, bumper_id):
        now = await self._now()
        bumper = {"id": bumper_id, "date": now.strftime("%S:%M:%H:%d:%m:%Y:%z")}
        bump_db.insert_one(bumper)
```

Example of a successful bump insert
_id
:
629385d8a441ee722cc76336
id
:
736933464292589568
date
:
"24:40:14:29:05:2022:+0000"

Comment: there is no error, the program runs fine but it didn't do what i intended it to do :(

Comment: "the program runs fine but it didn't do what i intended it to do" doesn't give much information. What *specifically* is the problem?

Comment: the line if now > (last_bump_time + timedelta(hours=2)):doesn't seems to work, it will return true anyways, resulting in the bot keep sending the bump reminder message again and again.

Comment: It could be the `_last_bump_time` not being timezone aware. Try this using unix timestamps (`time.time()` or `datetime.timestamp()`) and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: so i should save the datetime object as a timestamp in the database and then retrieve and turn it back into a datetime object? How do you I turn a timestamp back into a timezone aware datetime object

Comment: i tested the _last_bump_time's .tzinfo() it returns utc so I think it is timezone aware

Comment: Try printing out the formatted text / timestamp of `last_bump_time + timedelta(hours=2)` and `now`. I still feel like they aren't what you think they might be.

Comment: When i do print((last_bump_time + timedelta(hours=2)),now)
it returns `2022-05-29 08:48:49+00:00 2022-06-17 07:23:30.824728+00:00`
But then after bumping, the last bump time don't seems to update as it keep printing out the previous last bump time, so that's the problem.

Comment: Resulting in the bot keep sending the reminder message as now is still > last bump time.

Comment: But when I check the database by going to the database dashboard manually, the last_bump_time's record is logged into the mongodb databese, so I don't know why last_bump_time is not updated.

Comment: I'm not an expert in mongodb but I suspect it's because you aren't deleting the last entry / clearing the db when you add new ones into it.

Comment: i will need to store all the previous bumps to calculate who bumped the most in the past week based on the bump time, so I can't delete the last entry

Comment: But you would need to find out which one is the correct one you should be going off of. You might be getting the incorrect bump date. Try getting the max value of all of them, or sorting, etc.